# 3D reconstruction visualization ideas - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, visualization, 3d-reconstruction

I have some 3D reconstructed data which I need to visualize in MATLAB. It's quite a lot of data approx 1000x1000x1000, so naturally I most do some efficient visualization.

Any ideas how to visualize it, both in terms of 2D and 3D?

Thanks

Comment: Some suggestions: use three 2D projections in different figures; check [`slice`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/slice.html); check [`contourslice`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/visualize/techniques-for-visualizing-scalar-volume-data.html)

Comment: What is the nature of the data? What does it represent? Any comments on the range of values would be also valuable

Comment: 2D surf (colormap) where your 3'rd dimension is in logarithmic form (assuming others are fairly linear) to visualise the full range (if appropriate). A function based on distribution could possibly be used to ensure all data is visualised correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use 3D scatter plot in MATLAB:

> scatter3(outX,outY,outZ,[size of point], [color value for each point] )

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter3.html